# Generating Church Encoded Numbers for Arbitrary Integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lambda-calculus, newlisp

I want a function that takes an integer and returns that number in the form of a [church encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) function.

I have achieved this in newlisp:

```
(define (reduce stencil sq) (apply stencil sq 2))
(define (num n)  (cond
   ((= n 0) 'x)
   ((< n 2) '(f x))
   (true (reduce (fn (l i) (list 'f l)) (cons '(f x) (sequence 2 n)) ))))
(define (church-encode n)
  (letex ((body (num n)))
    (fn (f x) body)))
```

If I call (church-encode 0) I get back a lambda of the church-encoded zero:

```
(lambda (f x) x)
```

And (church-encode 3) will yield:

```
(lambda (f x) (f (f (f x))))
```

But I want to do the same in Javascript.  Preferably without resorting to string jank like I have done here:

```
(function (_) {
    var asnum = function(x) { return x((function(x) {return x+1;}), 0); };
    function church_encode(n) {
        function genBody() {
            return _.reduce(_.range(n), function(e,x) {
                return e.replace("x", "f(x)");
            }, "x");
        }
        eval("var crap = function (f, x) { return "+genBody()+"; }");
        return crap;
    }
    var encoded_nums = _.map(_.range(11), church_encode);
    var numerics = _.map(encoded_nums, asnum);
    console.log(numerics);
})(require('lodash'));
```

Comment: It would be nice if you included your newlisp code *in the question* with a brief description of how it works.

Comment: What is your question? What problems do you have with your JavaScript version of the code?

Comment: @Bergi Really? "Preferably without resorting to string jank." It's obvious that the propsed javascript is horrendously bad and there must necessarily be better ways to do it than resorting to eval. This is lambda calculus after all, so it's all masturbation. :P

Comment: @Squirrelsama: I asked before he posted his code…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    function range(n){
        var l = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            l.push(i);
        }
        return l;
    }
    function church_encode(n) {
        if(n < 1)
            return function(f, x) { return x; };
        if(n === 1)
            return function(f, x) { return f(x); };

        function succ (n) {
            return function(f,x) {
                return n(f,f(x));
            }
        }
        return range(n).reduce(function(a){
            return succ(a);
        }, function (f,x) { return x; });
    }
    function to_int(f){
        var i = 0;
        f(function(){ i++ });
        return i;
    };
    console.log(to_int(church_encode(5)));
})();
```